# Регулярное выражение для поиска даты в тексте с учетом разных форматов

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно составить регулярное выражение что бы оно находило в тексте дату в разных форматах, при том записывая в совпадения только число и месяц (для дальнейего анализа), должно находить дату в следующих форматах:

01/12 1/11 (01/12/2001 1/11/2001)

22.12 3.11 (22.12.2002 3.11.2002)

02-09 4-08 (02-09-1999 4-08-1999)

2 мар       17 фев (2 мар 2007 17 фев 2007)

3 апреля       22 января (3 апреля 1989  22 января 1989)

для дат без текстовых названий месяцев я использую такое регулярное выражение

```
 /(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])/
```

Вроде работает правильно
1. скажите пожалуйста на сколько такое выражение составлено грамотно? можно ли его улучшить? просто для проверки составил ли я его без косяков?

для дат где присутствуют буквенные названия месяцев пробую так:

```
 /(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- _](янв|фев|мар|апр|май|нюн|июл|авг|сен|окт|ноя|дек)/
```

и ещё одно для названий с полным месяцем

```
 /(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- _](января|февраля|марта|апреля|мая|нюня|июля|августа|сентября|октября|ноября|декабря)/
```

2. Эти два выражения почему то работают не совсем правильно, выдают не точные совпадения как правильней в этом случае? Можно ли как то объединить эти 2 последних выражения в одно что бы оно тригереилось на сокращённые названия и полные? о том что бы объединить все 3 выражения в одно я пока молчу, но если есть способ то скажите пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш регекс для цифровых дат следует дополнить блоком `[ \/\.\-]`:

```
/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[ \/\.\-]/
```

А для текстовых дат - посложнее:

```
/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]) (янв(?:аря)?|фев(?:раля)?|мар(?:та)?|апр(?:еля)?|мая|июн(?:я)?|июл(?:я)?|авг(?:уста)?|сен(?:тября)?|окт(?:ября)?|ноя(?:бря)?|дек(?:абря)?)/
```

Очень рекомендую сайт [regex101](https://regex101.com/) - отлично подходит для разработки и тестирования регексов

Когда Вы введете свое первое выражение, то увидите, почему оно отрабатывает неправильно.