# Регулярное выражение для даты в Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть большой набор данных с комментариями к фин. операциям.

В комментариях иногда пишут дату начисления, в любом удобном формате. Мне нужно ее считывать независимо от формата.

Допустим есть коммент:

```
"Дата начисления 21.04.2022"
```

Отсюда мне надо вытащить только "21.04.2022" и преобразовать в единый формат `2022-04-21`

Или, например:

```
"Дата начисления: 21/04/2022"
```

Задача та же, независимо от разделителей.

В `AppsScript` делал это регулярным выражением

```
/\d{2}(\D)\d{2}\1\d{4}/g
```

через `String.match()`, попробовал через `re.match` через то же выражение прокрутить строку, но это не работает почему-то.

Подскажите, что можно сделать. Возможно, есть более простой способ в питоне это реализовать

Так это было в AppsScript

```
acc_date = d.comment.toString().match(/\d{2}(\D)\d{2}\1\d{4}/g);
```

Так в Питоне

```
accDate = re.match("/\d{2}(\D)\d{2}\1\d{4}/g", str(transcation['comment']), flags=0)
```

Comment: ну насчет регулярки проходящей по всем типам написанных дат, есть ответ тут - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/967265/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: насчет изменения строки, можно станцевать с str.replace(old, new[, count])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пользовал одно время вот эту [штуку](https://pypi.org/project/datefinder/).

Пример использования

```py
import datefinder

a = datefinder.find_dates('"Дата начисления 21.04.2022". Отсюда мне надо вытащить только "21/04/2022"') 
b = list(a)
print(b)

# OUT
# [datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 21, 0, 0)]

print(b[0].date().isoformat())

# OUT
# '2022-04-21'
```

Comment: Супер, это то, что я искал!

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @ВладиславТихонов на здоровье

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте начать с чего-то такого:

```
import re

a = "Дата начисления: 21/04/2022"
res = re.sub(r"[/\\.]", "-", re.search(r"(\d+.*?\d+.*?\d+)", a).group(1))

print(res)
```

> 21-04-2022

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
a = "Дата начисления 21.04.2022 Дата начисления 21/04/2021"
date = [ f'{i[2]}-{i[1]}-{i[0]}' for i in [x.replace(".", "/").split('/') for x in re.findall(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}', a)]]
print(date)
```

Если разложить

```
import re
a = "Дата начисления 21.04.2022 Дата начисления 21/04/2021"
# Находим все даты в строке
date = re.findall(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}', a)
date_list = []
for i in date:
    # Разделяем дату по . или /
    i = i.split('.') if '.' in i else i.split('/')
    date_list.append(f'{i[2]}-{i[1]}-{i[0]}')
print(date_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Разделяем split() на части;
2. Метод datetime.strptime() анализирует входную строку с заданным форматом datetime и возвращает объект datetime.

```
import datetime

s = "Дата начисления 21.04.2022"

lst = s.split()

print(lst[2])

date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(lst[2], "%d.%m.%Y")

print('Дата:', date_time_obj.date())
```

ВЫВОД:
21.04.2022
Дата: 2022-04-21

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: 21/12/2002 - для таких не робит :(

Comment: В данном случае split делит строку на список, индекс не всегда 2-ой, допустим коммент может быть такой: "Оплатили заранее. Дата начисления: 21.04.2022", тогда lst[2] не сработает. И данный метод работает только на xx.xx.xxxx, на xx/xx/xxxx, например, работать не будет(

Comment: Хех, меняете условие и вперед.

Comment: В каком смысле? Мне нужно их обрабатывать не создавая огромные горы if elif, идеальным будет такое же регулярное выражение, как в AppsScript, оно работало